# Prestashop 1.6.0.9 Error sign up user

Tags: prestashop, registration, sign

I'm creating my first e commerce using *prestashop 1.6.0.9* but when I try to register one user i obtain the *error*:

> "TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to load form. Details: Error thrown: [object
>   Object] Text status: parsererror"

Anyone knows how can i fix it?

My website is: http://www.studio10-ecommerce.es/

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object syntax is broken by a PHP error. You can either:

- Check your PHP error log;
- Add a `console.log(data);` to the JavaScript file to see the actual response